# Are there workarounds to System.Zip which allow progress to be displayed?

Tags: delphi, zip, delphi-xe

I am attempting to use Delphi's built in System.Zip tool for compression. However, many of the situations with which I would use compression have significant number and sizes of files. Is there a way to hook into System.Zip to obtain and display progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in library exposes no mechanism for progress callbacks. There are no opportunities for you to hook into the compression (or decompression) process. Without modifying the built in library, you have no opportunity to receive progress.

So, modifying the built in library is one option, but probably not the best. The most attractive option, in my view, would be to use a library that did support compression. I think that tpAbbrevia is the most full featured Delphi compression library.

Comment: That's the answer that I expected, but hoped otherwise. If no other tricks appear, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Abbrevia is the way that I will proceed then. Thanks David.